# SQLiteOpenHelper static methods best practice

Tags: android

I have a class extending `SQLiteOpenHelper` to manage my database stuff.  I find it rather tedious to be writing code like this to use my database(`DBHelper` is the `SQLiteOpenHelper` object):

```
DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
FeedResponse feedResponse = dbHelper.getFeedResponse(...);
dbHelper.close();
```

**Is there anything wrong with replacing the above code with a static method and using it like this? Where might I run into trouble when implementing my database access like this?**

`FeedResponse feedResponse = DBHelper.getFeedResponse(context, ...);`

```
public static FeedResponse getFeedResponse(Context context, ...) {
    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    FeedResponse feedResponse = dbHelper.getFeedResponse(...);
    dbHelper.close();
    return feedResponse;
}

public FeedResponse getFeedResponse(...) {
    //returns data from database
}
```

Doing this really cuts down on always creating(typing out) a new instance of `DBHelper` and also closes it without a fuss.  It's all taken care of behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should work, but isn't optimal as you'll create a new DBHelper object for each database query. And the creation of an object is a expensive operation. It would be better if you reuse the DBHelper object.

Answer (score 0):

Also you may have troubles using your `DBHelper` from multiple threads.